# How to connect a transparent Oled display to raspberry pi using GPIO?

Tags: display

I'm a newbie to electronics and recently found a transparent Oled and want to connect it to a raspberry pi as a screen. How do I do that? There's the link to the display specifications:
https://m.alibaba.com/product/60062973863/2-4inch-transparent-OLED-screen-240/specifications.html?spm=a2706.7835515.1998800312.15.dI3DVB
[image: spec]

Comment: Did you get pin definition from the seller? You can drive this IC with 8080 16-bit parallel interface, i think you might modify current similar driver for this IC. But this would still require a lot of work to drive it.

Comment: The pin is a mpu-8080 8-bit parallel

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to go on there.

The screen uses an 8-bit parallel interface rather than the more common SPI interface.  Potentially that sounds faster but in practice I expect it will be slower, as the Pi has hardware SPI support but doesn't have hardware parallel interface support.

The driver IC is the DA8620.

I suggest you look through /boot/overlays/README to see if you can find a device tree overlay matching the above.

Failing that look through https://github.com/notro/fbtft

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I said I'm a newbie. Could you write it step-by-step and in simpler words? Thanks

Comment: @Artus90 Given that you're not comfortable with hardware development, this part is not for you. It is likely to require a significant amount of work to interface to the Pi, if it's possible at all (and it may not be). Find something else.

Comment: @Artus90 I echo duskwuff's comment.  These devices are in no sense newbie territory.  Put your money into something which is known to work on the Pi and make sure it is compatible with an existing device tree overlay (i.e. is mentioned in /boot/overlays/README).

Comment: I know that. But what I want to have is a transparent display, so I can see what's behind the display. If you have any solution for that problem or any other product which is transparent and has about 2-3inches, could you post it? Thanks

Comment: Finally decided to buy another lcd, though there were no drivers for this one.

Answer (score -1):

Well I can explain, what kind of raspberry pi do you have? If you carefully look at the board near the edge(the opposite side of the USB edge) you will see a black thing and I'd you carefully look at the labeling on the board it will say 'display' take your screen and the cable, and try to fit in the cable in that and voila it's working

Comment: That's for MIPI displays. The display described in the question is not one.

Comment: I have a rpi B+, but I don't have the display itself. I posted the question here before buying the display, because I don't want to buy something which doesn't work